# Creating a SOAP client

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

How can I send data to WSDL? Below is an example of the XML I have:

```
<UzbRequest xmlns="XXXXXXXX">
<Authorisatie>
    <Afzender>YYYYYYYY</Afzender>
    <Sleutel>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Sleutel>
</Authorisatie>
<Aanlevering ID="IDENTYFIKATOR">
    <Mutaties>
        <Mutatie ID="IDENTYFIAKTOR1" BSN="ZZZZZ" Collectiviteit="WWWWW">
            <Aanmelding>
                <Ingangsdatum>RRRRR</Ingangsdatum>
                <Geboortedatum>TTTTT</Geboortedatum>
                <Geslacht>M</Geslacht>
                <NAW>
                    <Naam>
                        <Voorletters>CP</Voorletters>
                        <EigenNaam>
                            <Achternaam>NOWAK</Achternaam>
                        </EigenNaam>
                    </Naam>
                    <DomicilieAdres>
                        <Straat>BLOTNA</Straat>
                        <Huisnummer>5</Huisnummer>
                        <Postcode>47-120</Postcode>
                        <Plaats>WARSZAWA</Plaats>
                        <Landcode>PL</Landcode>
                    </DomicilieAdres>
                </NAW>
                <Nationaliteit>
                    <Landcode>DE</Landcode>
                </Nationaliteit>
                <E106>Nee</E106>
            </Aanmelding>
        </Mutatie>
    </Mutaties>
</Aanlevering>
</UzbRequest>
```

How should I send these to a server?

What more information do I need to know to send data? I'm currently trying with `nusoap`. 
I'm trying to send this data as XML an array but nothing works.
Function `getFucntions` in PHP returns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(39) "UzbResponse Uzb(UzbRequest $UzbRequest)" }
```

---

I change type of conections with __soapCall.
Now I haveing error

`"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'Authorisatie' property"`
i have

```
$param=array(
    'Authorisatie'=>
        array('Afzender'=>array("_"=>'test')
            ,'Sleutel'=>array("_"=>'test12344')
            ));
var_dump($client->__soapCall("Uzb", $param));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use php's SoapClient - http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php.

You need to pass the parameters as an array and it will generate the XML itself. See the examples how it's done.